# React Native (0.63) Alert disappear automatically in IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, alert, react-native-ios

I am using **RN 0.63** and i am facing issue in React Native core alert.It popup and disappear automatically with second.I want alert should disappear when i click on OK button.

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  msg, // <- this part is optional, you can pass an empty string
  [
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

Comment: hello. did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and was able to avoid the "automatically disappearing" Alert popup after finding a `loading` prop was being passed down into a child component and was being (unnecessarily, in my case) consumed.
So I resolved the issue by simply removing the prop and handling the "loading" logic in the parent component.

Please double check that there are no unintentional re-renders of your component that may cause the Alert to be dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are showing dialog right after **setState**. You need to show dialog once the state update is completed. If this is not doable, it's not a good idea but a workaround then simply wrap dialog within **setTimeout**.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Title",
    "Message",
    [
      {
        text: "OK",
        onPress: () => {},
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
}, 100);
```